# Determine whether or not function is injective and whether or not it is surjective ${f (n, m) = (n^2 + 4, 2 − 2m)}$

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, definition

So I got this question.

Give the denominators of injectivity and surjectivity (for the function $f : X → Y )$ and then study the injectivity and surjectivity of the function $f :\mathbb{Z}^2 →\mathbb{Z}^2$ given by the formula:

$f (n, m) = (n^2 + 4, 2 − 2m)$

To show that it's not injective I did:

$f (1, 0) = (n^2 + 4, 2 − 2m) = (5,0)$

$f (-1, 0) = (n^2 + 4, 2 − 2m) = (5,0)$

So basically I completely don't understand the surjectivity part, can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Use the definition of surjectivity. Can $n^2+4$ attain all integer values?

Comment: I shortend your LaTex code here and there. Note that you do not have to write the brackets {...} in general. They will not interact on there own, so you have some missunderstanding with the typesetting there, which is of course no problem, but this will safe you some effort in the future. Feel free to look at the edit just made.

Answer (score 2):

It is not surjective because you always have $n^2+4\geqslant0$. So, for instance, $(0,0)$ is not in the range of $f$.